# Can huge error log cause performance issues?

Tags: nginx, freebsd

We have big nginx error log(1GB).

Can this cause serious performance issue while nginx writes new errors in that file?

Sometimes our webserver hangs and recovers itself for about 2 minute.

OS: FreeBSD 8

Comment: I would expect constant issues rather than intermittent ones. Have you tried truncating the log file (after backing it up) to see if the problem goes away?

Comment: Does nginx open file(read) then write into it? Because in this case, it will cause 2-3 minute heavy load.

Comment: I don't know for certain, but truncating the log file would eliminate the size as being the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it depends on nginx implementation details. 
In theory if nginx internally only opens a log file for append, then I would not expect performance issues from the large size. 
I recommend has a general good practice to have a log management strategy in place. Truncating the log or other strategy may be used to mitigating the risk of degradation with disk fragmentation or running out of free space.